# It is possible to search in files on ftp in Python?

Tags: python, ftp

right now this is all I have:

```
import ftputil

a_host = ftputil.FTPHost("ftp_host", "username","pass") # login to ftp

for (dirname, subdirs, files) in a_host.walk("/"): # directory
    for f in files:
        fullpath = a_host.path.join(dirname, f)
        if fullpath.endswith('html'):
            #stucked
```

so I can log in to my ftp, and do a .walk in my files
the thing I am not able to manage is when the .walk finds a html file to also search in it for a string I want.

for example:

on my ftp - there is a index.html and a something.txt file 
I want to find with .walk the index.html file, and then in index.html search for 'my string'

thanks

Comment: Is your remote host is Linux or Windows?

Comment: my remote host linux

Comment: Then why don't you use `paramiko` ssh module, which gives you more `ssh` features to deal with remote hosts.

Answer (score 1):

FTP is a protocol for file transfer only. It has not the ability by itself to execute remote commands which are needed to search the files on the remote server (there is a SITE command but it can usually not be used for such a purpose because it is not implemented or restricted to only a few commands).

This means your only option with FTP is to download the file and search it locally, i.e. transfer the file to the local system, open it there and look for the string.